# error in associations using belongs_to

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

i have a two tables, say e.g. Payment and refund with transaction_id as foreign key for refund.

```
defmodule Payments.Payment do
    use Payments.Web, :model

    schema "payment" do
        field :payment_id, :string
        field :captured_amount, :decimal
        field :transaction_id, :string
        timestamps()
    end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
        struct
        |> cast(params, [:payment_id, :transaction_id, :captured_amount]) 
        |> validate_required([:payment_id, ::transaction_id, :captured_amount])
    end
end


defmodule Payments.Refund do
    use Payments.Web, :model

    @primary_key {:refund_id, :string, []}
        schema "refund" do
        field :state, :string
        field :pay_id, :string
        field :amount, :decimal
        field :create_time, Ecto.DateTime      
        belongs_to :transaction_id, Payments.Payment

        timestamps()  
    end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ []) do
        struct
        |> cast(params, [:refund_id, :state, :transaction_id,  :pay_id, :amount, :create_time])
        |> validate_required([:refund_id, :pay_id, :amount])
    end
end
```

it is not able to insert the refund details, with no functional clause matching error.
I believe issue is with the changeset, as i am unable to work with it.

Comment: Can you add the complete exact error message? One problem I can see is that you haven't defined a `foreign_key` for the belongs_to. You probably want `belongs_to :payment, Payments.Payment, foreign_key: :transaction_id, references: :transaction_id` since you want to connect the `transaction_id` fields of the two tables.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert, but now i am getting this error.

* (Ecto.ChangeError) value `#Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :transaction_id is not loaded>` for `Payments.Refund.transac
tion_id` in `insert` does not match type :id

Comment: Also, i get  this error, 
as it tries to rollback 
errors: [transaction_id: {"is invalid", [type: :id, validation: :cast]}],

Answer (score 0):

When you want to build associations like this, you have to remember about few things:

**1. If one model `belongs_to` another, the second one `has_many` of them or `has_one` of it.**

In your example `Payments.Payment` should has one `Payments.Refund`.

**2. If you change in schemas, first you change in migrations.**

Your migration for table `refunds` should look like this:

```
def change do
  alter table(:refunds) do
    add :payment_id, :integer
  end
end
```

**3. When using associations in Ecto, you have to be explicit.**

Ecto doesn't preload your associations, you have to tell that you want to preload them with `Repo.preload(model, :field)` or simply using query with option `preload: [:field]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @patNowak, but how can a payment have many Refund, there is one transaction, and can have either one refund or no refunds at all. that is why it should be has_one, however i just want to associate Refund table with Payment, when there there is refund for any transaction, which is a rear case, not everytime i will have to refund the transaction, So used belongs_to in Refund schema. has_many is not an option

Comment: So you should use this `has_one` for `Refund`.